# iptables - How do I restrict access to just local devices on the network?

Tags: networking, iptables, vpn, firewall, wireguard

I have asked this question on SuperUser but the only response was from someone who I was unable to understand

I have a WireGuard VPN Server running on a Debian 12 host with no problems, listening on a specific UDP port, and all is working great with no issues.  I can connect from my phone WireGuard client while on 5G etc and all works as intended.

However I want to temporarily allow somebody access to this server, but restrict them to only accessing devices on my local network, 192.168.0.x - No access to the public internet once they are connected to the VPN so they can't visit general websites etc. just access devices on 192.168.0.x as needed

I am just a novice home user and tried this set of commands:

```bash
iptables -I OUTPUT -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT; iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport ##### -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport ##### -j ACCEPT
```

where ##### is the correct listening port to the outside world.  And on the host, generally seems to work as intended - I can communicate with all 192.168.0.0 devices and nothing outside of that scope - only problem is, I can also no longer connect via 5G to ######, my previously working VPN listen port.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Edit:

Another user told me to try FORWARD so I tried this but still no change, the daemon did not answer when tried from the outside world

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT; iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -m udp --sport ##### -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -m udp --dport ##### -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: what is the business related question in here? please also read carefully [ask]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following is correct

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s x.x.x.x -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s x.x.x.x -j DROP
```

Where `x.x.x.x` is the address you've assigned for the restricted client, which is enforced by the allowedips on your wireguard server.

Answer (score -1):

You can access devices within your local network but can't access the internet

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

And this rule allow incoming WireGuard taffic on the port

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport #### -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: This is only going to restrict packets generated by the router itself, packets coming in through the wireguard interface and being forwarded don't hit the `OUTPUT` chain